# Get a form id and then use it as a div name

Tags: jquery

I have a series of forms on a single page. I'm trying to grab the id of the specific form being submitted and  use that exact value as the name of the div to insert some html into. The div already exists with the that name.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.allforms').submit(function (ev) {
        Var myID = $(obj).attr("id");
        esv.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/update",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $(myID).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I give the divs the same name the data is returning correctly but only being displayed in the first div, so I know the server side is working. I've just started with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

change these:

```
Var myID = $(obj).attr("id"); // 'var' keyword should be lowercase
esv.preventDefault(); // you are passing event object as `ev` not `esv`
```

to:

```
var myID = $(this).attr("id"); // 'this' refers to the current form
ev.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myID = $(this).attr("id");
```

this will return the ID of form

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(function () {
    $('.allforms').submit(function (ev) {
        Var myID = this.id; // this refers to the form, and id is a droperty of the element so you can access it directly..
        ev.preventDefault(); // esv -> ev as that is the name you use as the parameter
        $.ajax({
            url: "/update",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#' + myID).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This pretty much did it. Thanks very much this was doing my head in. I needed to edit the final section to:  $("div#" + myID).html(data); To make sure it put the data into the correct div and not into the form.

Comment: @geof, id properties **must** be unique in the document.. Better use a fixed prefix to make them unique between forms and containers.. like for form `id="yourid"` and for div `id="yourid-container"`. This will make the document valid and you can target it with `$('#' + myID + '-container').html(data);`